# IP Security and Always On Setting in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, security, web-config

I have a continuous WebJob running on an Azure web app, which requires me to keep keep the app "Always On."  On that same app, I've set up the web.config file to block unlisted IPs with a NotFound error:

```
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
    <add ipAddress="123.456.789.123" allowed="true"/> <!--office-->
    <add ipAddress="168.62.180.0" allowed="true"/> <!--azure (for Always On setting)-->
  </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

Apparently the Always On setting causes Azure to ping the website every 5 minutes in the background, but the security options are blocking Azure's pings, which is cluttering up the error logs.  The other whitelisted IP addresses are able to access the app fine, though; it's just the Azure pings that are blocked.

Here's a screenshot of the error log from one of the blocked pings:

[image: App insights log of 404 for get request to /]

Any insights into how to allow in the Azure pings would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A good starting point might be to verify that this is indeed what's blocking that GET request; can you disable the ipSecurity rules temporarily, see if the keep alive request from Azure is still blocked, and then re-enable the rule?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I forgot to mention that we had actually already tried that.  We disabled the ipSecurity setting, and the errors stopped.

Comment: Ok. Also to do really basic troubleshooting here, the domain's root is accessible from that other whitelisted address, correct?

Comment: Correct.  There are actually a few others, and all of them are able to access the domain's root.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, did you find a solution @Sam?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  We've basically just been ignoring the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing both these IP worked for me. Since the ping for Always on was coming from "::1" ip, however I have also added "127.0.0.1" to the list.

```
<add allowed="true" ipAddress="::1" />
<add allowed="true" ipAddress="127.0.0.1" />
```